# Eliminar datos duplicados de un datagridview en c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image: rpn]tengo una duda, me gustaria eliminar las filas enteras donde se repita el mismo valor de la columna RPN, habra alguna instruccion que me pueda ayudar.

este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para llenar el datagridview.

```
public void Lista_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int x = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
                    {
                        int t = (i * j * k);

                        x++;

                        this.dgvlista.Rows.Add(x, i, j, k, i + "" + j + "" + k, (t));

                    }

                    total.Text = Convert.ToString(x);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué te parce si haces un Diccionario o un HashSet, y conforme vayas agregando, preguntas si existe dicho valor, al final a dicho Diccionario o HashSet lo mandas a la grid?

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario , investigare como hacerlo.

Comment: un gusto colaborar, dale con todo el power!!! Si luego te quedas estancado, edita la pregunta y agrega el intento. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Estaba revisando tu codigo y lo ideal seria usar HashSet para mantener solo valores unicos

```
int x = 0;
    HashSet<string> valoresUnicos = new HashSet<string>(); // Utilizamos HashSet para mantener un conjunto de valores únicos
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
            {
                int t = (i * j * k);
                string clave = i + "" + j + "" + k;
    
                if (!valoresUnicos.Contains(clave)) // Verificar si el valor ya existe
                {
                    x++;
                    valoresUnicos.Add(clave); // Agregar el valor al conjunto de valores únicos
                    this.dgvlista.Rows.Add(x, i, j, k, clave, t);
                }
            }
        }
    
        total.Text = Convert.ToString(x);
    }
```